# Joomla "Articles - Related" Module, Menu Assignment

Tags: joomla, module

I'm trying to add a default module (Articles - Related) on a Joomla site, but only on "Single Article" pages.

From the Menu Assignment of this module I select All Front End Views >>  Single Article (Alias: single-article)... but it doesn't render until I also select: Main Menu >> Menu Item ... Now the module renders on all the article pages of this Menu Item but also in the Menu Item page (witch is a Category Blog) - it just renders on the right side as an empty white div with an "Articles - Related" title and no content as there is none related to the page's main content.

Any ideas on how to make this module (and maybe others) apear only o "Single Article" pages ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In 3.3, you just set the related articles module to display on all pages, and it didnt display unless the user asks to see an article page.

Answer (score -1):

Agree that related articles module must be displayed only on article pages, even if categories are selected in its menu assignment settings. This feature must be in the module itself, default article related doesn't have that, and you won't be able to change this by changing Joomla settings.

I've made a lot of search for a good related articles solution for Joomla. This module shows up only on article pages.
Probably you'll also like this one: http://www.raxo.org/raxo-related-articles.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: >Any ideas on how to make this module (and maybe others) apear only o "Single Article" pages?    --- This guy was looking for a module that shows related articles only on article pages, and I gave him a direct and concrete answer. Your comment is irrelevant.